# XSLT 1.0 Given String break a given position if the position is space otherwise before that word

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT, I read some stuff on xslt. I could not able to achieve the solution.

My input is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <line1>Hello world, XSLT is Functional programming? additional info</line1>
</root>
```

Required output

```
<line1>Hello world, XSLT is<br/>Functional programming?<br/>additional info</line1>
```

My conditions is
total size of the `<DIV width="20pt">` for that I need to break the string according to max size of 20 characters IF String position is 20 contains space break and continue to next, Otherwise if String position is 19 contains space break with 19 position.

Sorry for the very bad english.

Let me know this can be done in XSLT, Here variables are immutable. I can't append the values.

Any hints plz......

Thanks,
Umesha

Comment: Any known browser will break/fit text in a `<div>` on his own. Is this really a requirement to insert `<br/>`?

Comment: I need to give some indent after the break because some email engines does't have text-indent negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you could use a recursive template to split the string by checking if there is a space in the 20th or 21st position. (Or if the length is less than 20 in the first place)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]" priority="2">
        <xsl:call-template name="split" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="limit" select="20" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Text length is less than or equal 20 characters -->
            <xsl:when test="string-length($text) &lt;= $limit">
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- 20th or 21st character is a space -->
            <xsl:when test="contains(substring($text, $limit, 2), ' ')">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1, $limit)" /> 
               <br />
               <xsl:call-template name="split">
                   <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(substring($text, $limit + 1))" />
               </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Find first space after 20th character and split on that -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1, $limit)" />  
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring(concat($text, ' '), $limit + 1), ' ')" /> 
               <br />
               <xsl:call-template name="split">
                   <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring($text, $limit + 1), ' ')" />
               </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited based on comment.

If you have access to xslt 2.0 you can use the following replace function.

```
<line1>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="."  regex=".{{1,20}}\s" flags="x">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>     
         <br>     
       </xsl:matching-substring>
       <xsl:non-matching-substring>
       </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </line1>
```

.{{1,20}}[\s]   Creates capturing groups of 1 to 20 characters in a greedy way (as many as possible) followed by [\s] any kind of whitespace. With the analyze-string function we select any matching substring and add a `<br/>` after it.

This example results in

```
<line1>Hello world, XSLT is <br/>Functional <br/>programming? <br/>additional <br/></line1>
```

Comment: Inserting markup as if it were text can be done if your processor supports disable-output-escaping, but it's never a good solution. Much better to use xsl:analyze-string and insert the `br` properly as an element node into the result tree.

Comment: @MichaelKay You are right, I only focused on the selection proces of the substrings. I changed the anwser to use the analyze-string function.